# Handling Brochure-style pages in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've built a number of ASP.Net MVC sites and in each of them there are a number of pages suited to MVC's Controllers and Actions, and a number of pages that are really just brochure pages - /why, /why/ouradvantage, /about, etc - pages that have no real functionality, just a View, maybe a Layout, and that's it.

For these brochure-style pages I'd really prefer to have just the View and a good Route to find it, so I could put the /why at /Brochure/Why.cshtml or /Brochure/Why/Index.cshtml and either way it will be picked up just fine. I'd like to avoid making silly Controllers and Actions (as I've done in the past) to handle this set of URLs and pages.

How can I go about this in an ASP.Net MVC project? This must be a common need.

EDIT: An example of how I can do this the verbose way:

I could use the standard MVC route ({controller}/{action}/{id}) and spam a bunch of useless Controllers to get the set of URLs and pages I want. Every time I want to add a brochure-style (no functionality, just a View) page I'd add a Controller or Action like this:

Why Controller:

```
public class WhyController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ViewResult OurAdvantage()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

This puts a View at /why and /why/ouradvantage - clean URLs. If I wanted an /about page, I could add another Controller that does nothing but return a View named AboutController. If it had 5 subpages I could add 5 Actions to that Controller, all of those Actions doing nothing but return a View.

If these brochure-style pages in the MVC site amounted to say, 100 pages, I'd have quite a few needless Controllers and Actions all doing nothing really. Not very DRY. I'm interested in a way to just put Views in a folder in my Project and have them accessible just for being there (Configuration through Convention), at clean URLs like /why and /why/ouradvantage.

There are a few ways that get me close:

I could put a bunch of .cshtml pages in and visit them directly - but then I have to have the file extension in the URL and the View files themselves have to sit in the root.

I could use ASP.Net Areas to define an Area for these, but then all brochure-style pages have to sit at least one URL segment deep and I still have the above problem of file extensions in URLs.

There are crazy Routes I can define.

I suspect this comes up often in MVC projects that have a small or large number of these Brochure-style pages - it seems like there should be a clean way to do this.

EDIT: A crappy solution that spams the routing engine.

Create a class that maps routes like:

```
public static void MapRoutes(RouteCollection routes, string appRoot, string path)
{
    if (!path.Contains("~/"))
        throw new NotSupportedException("Pages path must be virtual (use ~/ syntax).");

    var physicalPath = appRoot + path.Substring(2).Replace("/", "\\");

    var dir = new DirectoryInfo(physicalPath);
    var pages = dir.GetFiles("*.cshtml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    int rootLength = appRoot.Length;
    var rootParsed = pages.Select(p => "~/" + p.FullName.Substring(rootLength).Replace("\\", "/"));
    int folderPathLength = path.Length + 1;

    var mapped = rootParsed.Select(p => new {
        Url = p.Substring(folderPathLength, p.Length - 7 - folderPathLength),
        File = p
    });

    var routedPages = mapped.Select(m => routes.MapRoute(
        name: m.Url,
        url: "{*url}",
        defaults: new { path = m.File, Controller = "Brochure", Action = "Catchall" },
        constraints: new { url = m.Url }
    )).ToArray();
}
```

You can call this in RouteConfig like:

```
BrochureRoute.MapRoutes(routes, Server.MapPath("~/"), "~/Brochure");
```

That obviously maps all these pages to a BrochureController, which you'll need as well:

```
public class BrochureController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Catchall(string path)
    {
        return View(path);
    }
}
```

2 problems:

1. It spams the routing engine as I mentioned - if you have 100 pages you have 100 routes.
2. Passing the path as above seems to upset the normal Razor pipeline - visiting a page in this manner gets you an error like:

> The view at '~/Brochure/About.cshtml' must derive from WebViewPage

Comment: I don't completely understand behavior you want... Please  provide some more examples of routes and resulting actions in your post

Comment: @DaveA Updated to include a clearer example with code.

Comment: I think I understand. Would you be open to using Interchange-able Partials? This you can have a route that passes the partials name. The beauty is your routes would still look good, and you would have several controllers, each with a single View and countless partials in each Controller's dedicated View folder...

Answer (score 1):

To map individual pages [`RouteCollection.MapPageRoute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992955%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method can be used.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "why", "~/Brochure/Why.aspx");
```

<del>Sure, you could use Razor view engine (.cshtml) instead of WebForms.</del>

<del>[Check MSDN documentation for some more details.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#adding_routes_to_a_web_forms_application)</del>

---

**Update 2**

You are right you won't be able to use this for for .cshtml pages. However, you don't need to use routing to access Web Pages (.cshtml files). It is enough to create the files, and omit the extension in URLs. To achieve your desired structure you could do this:

- Your web project must allow Web Pages rendering. To enable this go to `web.config` and set `webpages.Enabled` to `true`. (`<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />`)
- Create folder `why` in your web application root
- Add MVC ViewPage named `Index.cshtml`. This will be accessible from http://yoursite.com/why
- Add MVC ViewPage named `ouradvantages.cshtml`. This will be accessible from http://yoursite.com/why/ouradvantages
- You will also be able to access url data using `@UrlData` collection

Check more about this [here](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/working-with-pages/creating-readable-urls-in-aspnet-web-pages-sites). More about Web Pages in general [is also available on asp.net website](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials).

If for some reason you really need to use routing, you'll need custom RouteHandler. You can [find one implemented on Nuget](https://nuget.org/packages/WebPageRouteHandler/). Usage examples of this package are [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/187/More-Flexible-Routing-For-ASP.NET-Web-Pages).

---

**Update**

If you'd like to avoid manually adding each route you have few choices.

**1) Create a convention to identify brochure pages**

You could do this by expecting URLs to be brochure pages by default, and isolating "non-brochure" pages to specific sections:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Default", "{brochurepage}", "~/Brochure/{brochurepage}.aspx");
// isolate non-brochure pages to "site" section
routes.MapRoute(
    "",
    "site/{controller}/{action}/{id}",                      // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

**2) Hold brochure page names in a collection**

```
List<string> brochurePages = new List<string>()
{ "about", "why", "contact" }; // add more pages here
....
foreach (var brochurePage in brochurePages)
    routes.MapPageRoute("", brochurePage, "~/Brochure/" + brochurePage + ".aspx");
```

---

I have to be very specific about two URLs you mentioned in your question. To implement routing for "/why" and "/why/ouradvantage" you will NOT be able to write elegant code. This will take special handling.

Comment: Indeed, but then I need to do MapPageRoute for every brochure-style page - not very DRY. If I have 100 brochure-style pages, I have to keep taking this extra step of adding these MapPageRoute calls to RouteConfig.cs. This probably also doesn't help performance-wise with the routing engine.

Comment: Key was to direct you to ASP.NET extension point that can be used to do this. It's DRY as my example is single page. For multi page, either 1) come up with a convention to identify brochure pages or 2) create a collection of page names and call `MapPageRoute` in a loop. I'll extend my answer with an example

Comment: That's getting much closer; the Collection you mention could be generated like Directory.FindFiles(Server.MapMath("~/Brochure"), "*.cshtml"). If the repeated calls to MapPageRoute just expand a simple hashtable the performance impact is negligible. Your note about subpages becomes an issue however, as does the simplicity of allowing either ~\why\index.cshtml or ~\why.cshtml. Much closer though.

Comment: You will have to be much more specific about kind of convention you wish to put in place if you wish a more specific answer than this. It might be possible to solve "/why", "/why/ouradvantages" being treated as two pages, but this would involve knowing priority which routing engine gives based on order of adding the route. It's not hard to find out, but I consider that risky as it could change in future version of ASP.NET.

Comment: I think your solution will do it if I can just wire up the mappings with a little code in RouteConfig - although it turns out MapPageRoute does not work with a .cshtml file as-is, so I need to figure out how to get that half to work first.

Comment: It appears this isn't possible simply because .MapPageRoute() is meant for .aspx pages only, not .cshtml pages - everything else about it does what I'm trying to do here. Unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is that you don't want to have separate controllers for all these "silly" pages, may I suggest that you create a logical way to route them to a singular controller and then render the correct data/ view based on the route?

For instance, your URLs could read "/Pages/Why/About" and you could route that to your pages controller and it would receive the "Why" and "About" as parameters and you could render your content accordingly.  Does that make sense?

Comment: This was the hacky-feeling approach I've taken in the past, that I was trying to avoid because it seems like any MVC project is likely to need these sorts of pages, and wiring them up should be trivial. It appears it IS trivial-ish if they're .aspx pages, but if you want to use Razor syntax - it requires this mess. I'll post a longer answer with code examples.

Comment: I've updated my question to include an example of this kind of solution - it's probably too spammy with the routing engine to make sense unfortunately.